# Failed to start SQL Shell (psql) of PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to this program and I found a problem when try to log in to start my programming. I get an error as shown in the figure below and stuck here for quite some time and I wonder it was came out with such strange characters. Hopefully could receive some recommendations and solutions over here.

[image]

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. What Encoding ("Language") do you use for the postgres and your terminal?

Comment: My computer regional language is English(U.K). How could I change it? Hmm

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the postgres via pgAdmin? Did it work? (Try it if you didn't already)

Comment: Ya..I tried..It works after I've Key in my password

Comment: Great. In pgAdmin you can check the encoding of the database. Its part of the properties of the Database. After you connect the database symbol changes (with an X before, and without after). Click it. Then you see the properties on the right. Look for "Encoding" or something.

Comment: my current encoding now is UTF8..it is correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38182/discussion-between-green-and-angelo-neuschitzer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have an encoding problem.
As you said in chat, your database encoding is UTF-8, while your shell encoding is CP-1252 ("Latin-1").

You need to switch your Terminal to UTF-8 (if thats possible on windows).

But most likely you want to use `pgAdmin` for your work. As long as you don't have a very specific reason to use the shell, its by far more convenient to use `pgAdmin`.